# DAX: Removing a filter for a measure in the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS query

Tags: dax

I'm struggling to create a DAX query to get the weekly sales amount and total sales amount (sum of all weeks together) on a same row. I'm filtering on item and year.

Example of a query:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Artikel[ART Artikel],
    Datum[Jahr-Woche],
    FILTER (
        Artikel,
        Artikel[ART ArtikelNr]="222834"
    ),      
    FILTER (
        'Datum',
        Datum[Jahr]="2022"
    ),
    "Sales Quantity ", [VK Menge],
    "Sales Quantity Total", CALCULATE([VK Menge], ALL(Datum[Jahr-Woche]) )
)
```

The `Sales Quantity Total` doesn't return the yearly total - it returns the same value as `Sales Quantity`. It seems that the `ALL()` function is not removing the filter from the column `Datum[Jahr-Woche])`:

[image: Try 1]

I've tried using `REMOVEFILTERS()`, etc. to no success.

What am I doing wrong?

*Note 1:*

When I remove the filtering on `Datum[Jahr]` from the query, the `ALL()` function starts working - the `Sales Quantity Total` returns the total sum. However - I need to filter on the year in the query... This behaviour is very confusing. :(

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Artikel[ART Artikel],
    Datum[Jahr-Woche],
    FILTER (
        Artikel,
        Artikel[ART ArtikelNr]="222834"
    ),      
    "Sales Quantity ", [VK Menge],
    "Sales Quantity Total", CALCULATE([VK Menge], ALL(Datum[Jahr-Woche]) )
)
```

[image: Try 2]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code and let me know If It works for you! Calculate evaluates external filters first, then internal filters!

```
YourMeasure =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Artikel[ART Artikel],
    Datum[Jahr-Woche],
    FILTER ( Artikel, Artikel[ART ArtikelNr] = "222834" ),
    "Sales Quantity ", [VK Menge],
    "Sales Quantity Total",
        CALCULATE (
            CALCULATE ( [VK Menge], Datum[Jahr] = "2022" ),
            ALL ( Datum[Jahr-Woche] )
        )
)
```

EXPLAIN Above Same Code:

[image: Image_Rest]